# Random lookups in large sparse arrays?

Tags: sparse-matrix, hdf5, random-access

Im using HDF5 to store massive sparse arrays in Coordinate format (basically, an M x 3 array which stores the value, x index and y index for each non-zero element).

This is great for processing the whole dataset in an iterative manner, but I am struggling with random lookups based on index values.

E.g, given a 100x100 matrix, I might store then non sparse elements like so:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], // Data values
 [13, 14, 55, 67, 80], // X-indices
 [45, 12, 43, 55, 12]] // Y-indices
```

I then wish to get all the data values between `10<x<32` and `10<y<32`, for example. With the current format, all I can do is iterate through the x and y index arrays looking for matching indices. This is very very slow, with multiple reads from disk (my real data typically has as size of `200000x200000` with perhaps `10000000` non-sparse elements).

Is there a better way to store large (larger than RAM) sparse matrices and support rapid index-based lookups?

I'm using HDF5, but happy to be pointed in other directions

Answer (score 1):

First, let's suppose that, as your example hints but you don't state conclusively, you store the elements in order sorted by `x` first and by `y` second.

One easy technique for more rapid lookup would be to store an `x-index-index`, a vector of tuples (following your example this might be `[(10,1),(20,null),(30,null),(40,null),(50,3),...]`) pointing to locations in the x-index vector at which runs of elements start. If this index-index fits comfortably in RAM you could get away with reading it from disk only once at the start of your computation.

Of course, this only supports rapid location of `x` indices, and then a scan for the `y`.  If you need to support rapid location of both you're into the realm of spatial indexing, and HDF5 might not be the best on-disk storage you could choose.

One thought that does occur, though, would be to define a `z-order curve` across your array and to store the elements in your HDF5 file in that order.  To supplement that you'd want to define a `z-index` which would identify the location of the start of the elements in each 'tile' of the array.  This all begins to get a bit hairy, I suggest you look at [the Wikipedia article on z-order curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) and do some head scratching.

Finally, in case it's not crystal clear, I've looked at this only from the point of view of reading values out of the file.  All the suggestions I've made make creating and updating the file more difficult.

Finally, finally, you're not the first person to think about effective and efficient indexing for sparse arrays and your favourite search engine will throw up some useful resources for your study.